# MissingPluginException No implementation found for method getApplicationDocumentsDirectory on channel plugins.flutter.io/path_provider

Tags: flutter, flutter-getx

**Error:** Unhandled Exception: MissingPluginException(No implementation found for method getApplicationDocumentsDirectory on channel plugins.flutter.io/path_provider).

this my code.

```
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';
import 'package:get/get.dart';
import 'package:get_storage/get_storage.dart';

class GetStoragePage extends StatefulWidget {
  const GetStoragePage({super.key});

  @override
  State<GetStoragePage> createState() => _GetStoragePageState();
}

class _GetStoragePageState extends State<GetStoragePage> {
  var data = GetStorage();
  var name = '123456';

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
      appBar: AppBar(title: const Text('Get Storage Demo')),
      body: Center(
        child: Column(mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.center, children: [
          Text(
            name,
            style: const TextStyle(fontSize: 30),
          ),
          const SizedBox(height: 50),
          Row(
            mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.spaceAround,
            children: [
              ElevatedButton(
                  onPressed: () {
                    data.write('name', 'John');

                    Get.snackbar('Seved', 'Data Save Successfully');
                  },
                  child: const Text("write")),
              ElevatedButton(
                  onPressed: () {
                    data.read('name');
                  },
                  child: const Text("read"))
            ],
          ),
        ]),
      ),
    );
  }
}
```

How to solve error, give advice.

Answer (score 0):

you have to initialize the getStorage before using it.
Usually, we call it before the run app function in the main.dart file,

like this,

```
   Future<void> main() async {
      await GetStorage.init();
      runApp(const Entry());
    }
```

Comment: I have already done the code you mentioned code, after that the error is coming.

Answer (score 0):

Your issue belongs to this package [path_provider](https://pub.dev/packages/path_provider). I mean, this package is responsible for that error.

So, now you've to confirm that you've implemented that package as a direct dependency in the pubspec.yaml file. Ensure you've been using the latest version from the pub dev site.

Now stop the project (if running) & open your project in the terminal window & Lastly, execute the below-mentioned commands one by one:

```
flutter clean

flutter pub get

flutter run
```